# React Mui css if condition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can i change the border radius of a card if the Typography is close? I just want that if the Typography is close the border radius of a card will be `borderRadius: '4px 4px 4px 4px !important'`

```
 <Card sx={{borderRadius: '4px 4px 0px 0px !important'}}>

    <Button
        onClick={setView}
        className="text-black"
        disableRipple={true}
      >
        <Typography sx={{ color: 'rgba(64, 66, 70, 1)' }}>
          {view ? 'Close' : 'View'}
        </Typography>
      </Button>
 />
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what you mean by "if the Typography is close?" Also, could you provide a link to the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well judging by the fact that you are doing conditional rending in the Typography component based on `view`, I'm willing to bet you could do the same with the Card component.

```
 <Card sx={{borderRadius: view? '4px 4px 4px 4px !important' : '4px 4px 0px 0px !important'}}>
```